# What does в сложн. сл. mean in Russian dictionary?

Tags: сокращения

What does ***в сложн. сл.*** mean in below screenshot (highlighted with red rectangle)? [Source](https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=-%D0%B4%D1%8E%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**"в сложн. сл."** stands for **"в сложных словах"** (**"in compound words"**).

For example, **"трехдюймовый"** - compound word (*сложное слово*) consisting of two words: **"трех-"** and **"-дюймовый"**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)